# How to use a for loop for this problem in Java

Tags: java

```
public class Lab2 {
    public static Cities [] PathSolution = new Cities[7];
    int PathIndex = 0;
    int StartCity;

    static Cities [] City = new Cities [4];
    public static void main(String[] args){
        for(int i = 0; i<City.length; i++)
            City[i] = new Cities();
        City[0].Initialization ( 0, 1, 1);
        City[1].Initialization ( 1, 5, 5);
        City[2].Initialization ( 2, 10, 3);
        City[3].Initialization ( 3, 2, 7);
```

I would like to use a for loop in this problem such that it would go through all the citites. for example:

```
    City[0].Distance(5, 5);
    City[0].Distance(10, 3);
    City[0].Distance(2, 7);
    City[1].Distance(1, 1);
    City[1].Distance(10, 3);
    City[1].Distance(2, 7);
    City[2].Distance(1, 1);
    City[2].Distance(5, 5);
    City[2].Distance(2, 7);
    City[3].Distance(1, 1);
    City[3].Distance(5, 5);
    City[3].Distance(10, 3);
```

Currently, I am manually typing the above code in order to go through all Cities using the "Distance" method that I have created. So right now I need to manually write City[0] - City[1], City[0] - City[2].. City[1] - City[0], City[1] - City[2] etc..

So basically I want each city to go through each city (except itself) using the Distance method.
Explaining the code:
The Initialization is in this format (cityID, cityX, cityY)
(The x and y are coordinates)
The Distance formula works like this:
City[a].Distance(x,y)
The x and y coordinates are the coordinates of the cities 0,1,2 and 3, and are currently being manually entered by me.
I would like to have a for loop that would go through all cities (except itself).

I was trying this for loop but it wasn't working:

```
for (int i = 0; i < City.length; i++) {
            City[i].Distance(5, 5);
            i++;
            City[i].Distance(10,3);
            i++;
            City[i].Distance(2,7);
            i++;
        }
```

This is the Distance Method:

```
public void Distance(float x, float y) {
        int dist = (int) sqrt(Math.pow(City_X_Location - x , 2) + Math.pow(City_Y_Location - y , 2));
        System.out.println(dist);
    }
```

This is what I get when I use the Distance Method:

```
City[0].Distance(5, 5);

3
```

This is the result I get when I type it manually and what I should get from the for loop:

```
3
8
0
6
8
0
6
3
0
6
3
8
```

Comment: Don't do `i++;` inside your for loop. You used the for loop and already defined `i++` as an increment operation that gets done after every iteration so there is no need to do it 3 more times per loop.

Comment: Please follow Java naming conventions: an initial lowercase letter for variable and method names (`city`, `pathIndex`, `startCity`, `initialization()`, `distance()`).

Comment: If I understand your logic correct you are trying to calculate the distance from every city to every other city. That might best be done with a nested loop. Does your cities class have methods to get its X and Y coordinates? So would something like `City[0].getXLocation()` be possible?

Comment: Yeah there is actually.. But the initialization is just always getting the last city to get the x and y values. Example if I write City[1].Get_X(), it still shows the x value of City[3], because i initialized it last..

Comment: "Example if I write City[1].Get_X(), it still shows the x value of City[3], because i initialized it last.." <- @NewCoder2001 This sounds like you declared those fields as `static` when they shouldn't be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a case where you want to "compare" an element of an array with eachother. I suppose that you do not mind small optimisation problems so I'm making it simple :

```
//Step 1 : iterate over all your cities.
for(Cities current : City) {
    //Step 2 : compare current city with eachother
    for(Cities other : City) {
        //Step 3 : make sure that you don't compare a city with itself
        if(!current.equals(other)) {
            //Step 4 : use the distance method using the other's coordinates :)
            current.Distance(other.City_X_Location, other.City_Y_Location);
        }
    }
}
```

This way, each element (first loop) will be compared with each other (second loop). The "if" statement is just made to be sure that you don't compare twice the same element.

I'm using the `city.City_X_Location` and `city.City_Y_Location` dirrectly as you show it in your Distance method, thinking that it would be a `public` attribute, but it would be better if you could make it private and create a `getCity_X_Location()` method.

Finally, if you're not used to use the `for(Item i : Iterrable)` syntax, feel free to turn these into `for(int i = 0; i < City.length(); i++)`